# How to quit my app from a non-activity app?

Tags: android, exit, activity-finish, quit

How does one quit an app from a non-activity/fragment? I have a class that handles events, and if a certain event happens, i wish to quit my app. I normally allow users to quit the app by doing the following:

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

However, I can't call getActivity() from a class that's not an activity or fragment.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "non-activity"?  Is it a service?  You can define your app as a Broadcast receiver and then broadcast some message from the service.  Then in `onReceive` of the activity use the code above (by the way, you don't need `System.exit(0)`)

Comment: instead getActivity(), insert your Activity`s name will do it.

Comment: Well if it was allowed to kill an app without any reference to its Context, then it could be easily be misused. I guess you need to have a reference to the activity on top of your activity stack to do this.

Comment: Pass in a reference to the activity, and call finish on it.

Comment: or simply pass a valid context and do your work

Comment: Gabe, do you mean something like what Matej answered below?

Illegal Argument, I have a context in the class, what can I do with it to finish the app/activity?